# Как получить логин Windows учетки клиента входящего на сайт?

Tags: python, django, request, ldap

У меня написан проект для внутренней сети, не получается взять логин винды клиента входящего на сайт, а он нужен, т.к. потом я его отправляю в ldap для авторизации... в поисках нашел обработку request.META['REMOTE_USER'] но добавив к себе эти настройки в итоге такой ключ не получаю... Очень нужна помощь, 4й день мучаюсь

Comment: Я видел такую штуку. Работает на связке авторизация NTLM + Ldap сервер. В хроме также работает, не только IE. В Апач (если он есть) нужно ставить доп модуль mod_ntlm, я не знаю есть ли он у вас. Но в любом случае, скорее всего придется ставить доп модули и в ваш веб-сервер. Такой функционал есть [в Битриксе](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/?COURSE_ID=26&LESSON_ID=1200). Я больше по пыху, если вы его знаете, скачайте битрикс и посмотрите как работает. Или погуглите `python ntlm ldap`. Вроде работает так: ntlm авторизация => ваш код => связаться с Ldap сервером.

Comment: Вот нашел такую штуку, похоже на ваш случай https://stackoverflow.com/a/43091875/9435985

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете IIS и Internet Explorer, вы можете включить «Встроенную проверку подлинности Windows» (проверка подлинности NTLM). Это заставляет IE автоматически аутентифицировать пользователя, используя инфраструктуру вашего домена. После автоматического входа в систему вы можете получить доступ к имени пользователя, используя переменную среды LOGON_USER. Для этой цели также существует модуль для Apache (mod_ntlm), хотя я не знаю его статуса.

Возможно, вы могли бы попробовать реализовать аутентификацию NTLM самостоятельно, но это, безусловно, потребует много работы.

Кроме этого, похоже, нет никакого другого способа, поскольку ни один разумный браузер не отправит имя пользователя ...

Ответ [Ferdinand Beyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34855/ferdinand-beyer) на [очень похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680804/is-it-possible-for-a-django-application-to-know-users-windows-domain-name/680838#680838).

Comment: Извините, но проект не запущен на сервере и вариант с IIS мне не подходит, он развернут на одном из пк сети.

Comment: Ещё раз проверьте этот ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680804/is-it-possible-for-a-django-application-to-know-users-windows-domain-name/680838#680838), похоже, было найдено решение. Или сразу [сюда](https://code.google.com/archive/p/python-ntlm/issues/4)

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит мучится. Вот канонический ответ от djangoproject . [Аутентификация с использованием REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/auth-remote-user/)

Comment: я пробовал использовать этот вариант. обновил MIDDLEWARE = [ ...  и так же добавил AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [ ... но это не помогло. ключ REMOTE_USER все равно не приходит. возможно этого не достаточно?

Comment: Чтобы получить REMOTE_USER запрос, нужно выполнить настройки IIS:
тут подробно 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881344/django-authenticate-using-logged-in-windows-domain-user